# How to open stream rather than loading whole file into memory inside pyhton lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hi I am new to lambda and python. 
I have a use case to read the content of a large file let's say gretaer than 1 GB and just log its content line by line.

I have made a lambda function as below :

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """Read file from s3 on trigger."""
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    file_obj = event['Records'][0]

    bucketname = str(file_obj['s3']['bucket']['name'])
    filename = str(file_obj['s3']['object']['key'])

    iterator = s3.Object(bucketname, filename).get()['Body'].iter_lines()
    for line in iterator:
        print(line)

    return 'Lambda executed successfully.'
```

But it is not printing anything inside logs.

I think `s3.Object(bucketname, filename).get()['Body']` is trying to load the whole file into memory. Is this my understanding is correct?
**because this is working fine for small files.**

If yes, then how can I open a file as a stream without loading it fully inside the memory.

Comment: please provide your event for understanding

Comment: @soheshdoshi thank you so much. You make me think about the source of the event. My lambda was only listening to put operation on S3, but the larger files are being uploaded to S3 via Multipart Upload instead of a regular Put operation. After configuring the lambda to listen "Multipart Upload", now it working fine.

Comment: sound interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(BUCKET, key)
for line in obj.get()['Body']._raw_stream:
    # do something with line
```